# How can I prevent strncpy_s from padding destination buffer in debug build?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

I maintain a fairly large piece of legacy code that still uses `strncpy` a lot. I have now started the process of replacing the usage of `strncpy` with its safe counterpart `strncpy_s`. I noticed that `strncpy_s` is padding the destination buffer with -2 values - but only in debug builds! In release builds no padding occurs.

For instance:

```
char buffer[3];
// buffer becomes 00000000  00000000  00000000
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
// buffer becomes 01100001  00000000  11111110
//                97 ('a')  0        -2
strncpy_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "a", _TRUNCATE);
// i is -2
int i = buffer[2];
```

The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dae5d43.aspx) do not mention this padding behaviour, and in my case it's really something I don't want because my legacy code relies on the fact that the zeroed parts of the buffer remain zeroed and are not overwritten during string copying.

Is there a way how I can prevent `strncpy_s` from padding the destination string in debug builds?

Note that I have tested this with both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right function to use? Not `strcpy_s`?

Comment: @Deduplicator You may be right, however `strcpy_s` has the same padding behaviour.

Comment: `strncpy_s` alludes to a relationship with `strncpy` which does not exist, and is thus doubly misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strcpy_s()` will fill in the buffer with `'FE'` in debug mode only.

You can turn this off explicitly by calling [_CrtSetDebugFillThreshold(0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms235389.aspx)

Comment: I only now noticed that the very last sentence of the `strncpy_s` documentation mentions this function. My bad... Anyway, I am accepting your answer because it's the one that actually solves my problem. Even if I use `strcpy_s` (as everybody else tells me to) I will have to call `_CrtSetDebugFillThreshold`.

Answer (score 8):

The definition of `strncpy_s` is that elements beyond the null terminator take unspecified values. The definition of `strncpy` is that those elements are set to `0`. If you don't want this behaviour, don't use `strncpy_s`.

Also, `strncpy_s` has different behaviour to `strncpy` in the case that the input is too big for the buffer.

There are few valid use cases for `strncpy` or `strncpy_s`.  It's almost always better to either use `strcpy`, `snprintf`, or `memcpy`. My preference would strongly be to use whichever of those three functions is best suited to the task.

Calling it a "safe counterpart" is rather an exaggeration, IMO.  The "non-safe" versions are actually all perfectly safe if you pass the correct arguments to them; and if you do not pass correct arguments then neither variety is safe.

If your code that uses `strncpy` is actually not bugged, and you rely on the zero-padding feature, then there is no reason to change it.

Comment: And like you explained, replacing `strncpy` with `strncpy_s` is almost always an error, and when it isn't `strcpy_s` or `strcpy` are superior alternatives. (I didn't know before that `strncpy_s` is totally borked in a completely different way from `strncpy`).

Comment: I will look into using `strcpy_s`, however `strcpy_s` has the same padding behaviour as `strncpy_s`. Also, I don't agree with your statement "The definition of strncpy_s is that elements beyond the null terminator take unspecified values." Is this stated somewhere in the docs? I couldn't find such a statement, neither explicit nor implicit.

Comment: Read the C11 standard, section K.3.7.1.4  . You can download a free draft by following links [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)

Comment: I was living under the impression that `strncpy_s` is a Microsoft specific function, but I may very well be wrong, so I downloaded the latest publicly available draft (N3797). In that draft, I could not find any mention of the function `strncpy_s`, nor of a section K.3.7.1.4.

Comment: N3797 is a C++ document. Look for N1570 from the C group. MS invented these _s versions and the C11 committee agreed to add them, so it seems likely that their C++ versions are the same.

Comment: Ah, found it! Thanks for educating me about the standards.